# String array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a problem inserting string elements in a string array... For example, I have a three assignment lines:

```
a = b
b = c
c = e
```

Then I want to insert these six variables in `string[]` variables.

I use the following code, but this code inserts only the last assignment variables (c, e).

```
for (int i = 0; i < S; i++)  // S = 3 number of assignment line
{
    variables = assigmnent_lines[i].Split('=');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<string> this_is_a_list_of_strings = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in assignment_lines)
{
    this_is_a_list_of_strings.AddRange(line.Split('='));
}
string[] strArray = this_is_a_list_of_strings.ToArray();
```

Comment: 'chars' is a deceptive name for a list of strings :)

Comment: Thank you jb., I edited my original answer. I don't want to confuse people interested to learn programming :)

Answer (score 0):

You are wiping out the variables property on each pass. It would be easier to use a collection property:

```
List<string> variables = new List<string>();

foreach (string sLine in assignment_lines)
{
   variables.AddRange(sLine.Split('='));
}

// If you need an array, you can then use variables.ToArray, I believe.
```

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of the for statement, you are restating what `variables` is.  Instead you should create the array as large as it needs to be and then set each index individually:

```
String[] variables = new String[S * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
    // you should verify there is an = for assuming the split made two parts
    String[] parts = assignment_lines[i].Split('=');
    variables[i*2] = parts[0];
    variables[i*2+1] = parts[1];
}
```

An easier alternative would be to use `List<String>` and add strings as you go dynamically.

Comment: This works using simple `String[]`, but as other answers have indicated, `List<String>` is much easier and in fact I recommend it more. This is just to show it can be done with arrays.