# NullRefererenceException

Tags: c#, string

```
foreach (string line in assigment_lines)
    {
        // Object reference not set to an instance of 
        chars.AddRange(line.Split('=')); object.
    }
   string[] strArray = chars.ToArray();
```

My program give me Null Reference Exception in above code what a problem ?

Comment: Either `chars` is null or one of the `line`s in `assignment_lines` is null.

Comment: Welcome to the site - please write a proper title in order for people to better understand your questions at a glance. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers for more.

Comment: Too localized. As a developer, this sort of thing *must* be debugged/fixed by yourself. Look at the call-stack, reason what value might be null, and/ or use a debugger. In the code posted there are only two member invocations on the line, which is why Justin Satyr could easily point out which expressions *could* be null.

Comment: @BoltClock Not sure there is a "proper title" for this question :(

Comment: His previous question is directly related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620629/string-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: Ok i change question title sorry for my noobness ..

Comment: Voted to close because "SO is not a debugger".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that line is not null also check where do you define chars array.
You can do something like this:

```
foreach (string line in assigment_lines)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) {  
      chars.AddRange(line.Split('=')); // Object reference not set to an instance of object.
  }
}
string[] strArray = chars.ToArray();
```

Comment: But one more question 4 u yesterday i run this program its running ok but when i run today it give me exception why ?

Comment: Perhaps you have used different data? Also could be that line.Split does return null if it can't split

Comment: @muhammad - its xmas eve so magical things tend to happen.  Or maybe assignment_lines is different for reasons only you can figure